# Allow only a single specific IP address on Nginx under reverse proxy

Tags: nginx

I have an api running on localhost. To allow external access to the API under a specific domain path I've set a reverse proxy. This part works fine. Now I'm trying to filter access and allow only a single IP to connect to the API, in other words, deny all IP's connections except from a specific one.

With the configuration bellow all IPs are being blocked successfully, but it's also blocking the one IP I want to allow. I've researched and tried several fixes and I suspect I need to get the real_IP under the reverse proxy, but haven't manage to make it work for my specific situation. All help is appreciated. Here's the code for my nginx config file inside sites-available:

```
server {

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name foo.com www.foo.com;

    location / {

        allow XX.XX.XX.XX;
        #allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny  all;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }


    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

XX.XX.XX.XX is the ip I want to allow which is actually the server's actual IP. But I don't think it makes a difference. I've also tried adding the following inside "location /{ }" scope, but no luck:

```
set_real_ip_from XX.XX.XX.XX;
real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive on;
```

Comment: use `ufw` and deny or allow ip addresses. or for flexibility fix Your code to check db for IP addresses that allowed

Comment: @numb3r thanks for your answer. I have other API's, APP's and several domains associated with this server. So I need to block IP's for this API but don't want the restrictions to apply to the other paths for other services I've set. This is all under the same IP address in the end. Is such a configuration possible with ufw? If so could you point an example? thanks

Comment: ufw does not resolve hostnames, so it cannot do smart firewalling depending on requested hostname.

Comment: Seems like You've problems with ip resolution. Cause I've just tested Your example. It works as intended. Let's enable access log and see which ip it's getting in request. Run in terminal `tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log` and in another terminal or browser try to do request. or disable allow deny rule and just add `app.use((req, res, next) => {console.log(req.ip); next();});` and catch that real ip

Comment: if You want to tell server to use loopback interface in requests to `foo.com` then add such line in `/etc/hosts`  :  `127.0.0.1   foo.com www.foo.com`  that will tell Your server to not request DNS server to resolve that hostname which will lead to request from outside.

Comment: @num8er Ok, it works because I messed up in the description/example. It's allowing 127.0.0.1 (localhost) inside the reverse proxy. Inside the reverse proxy everything comes from localhost anyway, so the example is actually the opposite problem: allowing all IP's. I've added a comment to this line to make the example match the description

Comment: Why not just remove that rules if You want to allow all IPs? But: `allow ip-here; deny all;` works. I think You've messed with `X-Forwarded-For`.

Comment: nono, I don't want to allow all IP's, just XX.XX.XX.XX and I haven't solved the problem yet. I guess my last comment is just a bit confusing, sorry. Anyway, I've updated the example, it had a mistake, could you try again and check if it still works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178820/discussion-between-num8er-and-david-neto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's good idea to put that control to web server level.

Giving access is more firewallish task.

But in some conditions when You want to give access to registered host dynamically without restarting or configuring somethings - it's better to make guard method on app level.

For now I can recommend one of these:

1) Put firewall in front of app or nginx. You may use [ufw](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04)

2) Put access control to app level. If it's nodejs app write middleware:

`middlewares/allowByIp.js` :

```
'use strict';

cons db = require('../database'); // mongoose models abstraction

const AllowedHosts = db.model('AllowedHost');

module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {

  const isAllowed = await AllowedHosts.findOne({ip: req.ip});
  if (!isAllowed) {
    res.status(403).send('Forbidden');
  }

  next();
};
```

or :

```
'use strict';

cons allowedHosts = [... ip listing ...]; // take care of graceful restarting of Your app when You'll modify this array

module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {

  const isAllowed = allowedHosts.includes(req.ip);
  if (!isAllowed) {
    res.status(403).send('Forbidden');
  }

  next();
};
```

in `app.js` :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const ipFirewall = require('middlewares/allowByIp');
app.use(ipFirewall);

...

app.listen(3000);
```

I've checked Your nginx example it works as expected.

So I suspect that nginx gets different ip. Check `/var/log/nginx/access.log` for real ip address that Your nginx gets when source part does request to destination.

But, if You want to limit access internally, to tell server to use loopback interface in requests to `foo.com` then add such line in `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   foo.com www.foo.com
```

it will tell Your server to not request DNS server to resolve that hostname which will give global ip and result with request from outside.